# Get json data as a string with comma(,) in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I get a JSON data from server look like:-

```
"skills": [
        {
            "957": "Modules",
            "958": "Sales and Distribution",
            "959": "Material Management",
            "960": "Finance",
            "961": "Controlling",
            "963": "Human Resource"
        }
    ],
```

I need to print data as:

**skillset ="Modules,Sales and Distribution,Material Management,Finance,Controlling,Human Resource"**

I try but not get sucess.

```
$scope.skillset = JSON.stringify($scope.skills);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to parse the json object and pick the first element of the parsed array. Then do transformations to get the needed string.

```
var obj = angular.fromJson($scope.skills)[0];
    //ES6
    var skillset = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
       return obj[key]
    }).join(',');

   //ES5
   var skillset = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
       return obj[key]
    }).join(',');
```

Here's a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nESH8iBz0dJc6X3lWTJH?p=preview)

Comment: it show error: **'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use esnext option)**. I am using IONIC v1

Comment: Use my ES5 code then. This version of ionic does not support es6 by default. Check my edited code

Answer (score 2):

```js
var skills= [
        {
            "957": "Modules",
            "958": "Sales and Distribution",
            "959": "Material Management",
            "960": "Finance",
            "961": "Controlling",
            "963": "Human Resource"
        }
    ];

var valueArray = Object.values(skills[0]);
console.log(valueArray.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.values() to get values of the JSON.

```
var skillValues = Object.values($scope.skills[0]);
$scope.skillset = skillValues.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple javascript `for`...

```
$http.get("your_json_data").then(
    function (res) {

        var skills = res.data.skills;
        var aux,
            aux2 = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
            aux = skills[i];
            for (k in aux) {
                if(aux.hasOwnProperty(k)){
                    aux2 += aux[k] + ",";
                }
            }
        }

        $scope.viewData = "skills=\"" + aux2.substring(0, aux2.length - 1) + "\"";
           //$scope.viewData is ready to be shown on the view
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a key-value loop to handle this.

```
var response = {
    "skills": [{
        "957": "Modules",
        "958": "Sales and Distribution",
        "959": "Material Management",
        "960": "Finance",
        "961": "Controlling",
        "963": "Human Resource"
    }]
}

var skills = response.skills[0];
var skillset = "";

for (var key in skills) {
    skillset += skills[key] + ', ';
}

console.log(skillset);
```